# Android Device Manager not Ringing

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, android-device-manager

The ring for 5 minutes function on Android Device Manager is a great tool that I have used multiple times to find my phone (which I happen to misplace quite often).

The thing is, it doesn't work.  Or rather, my phone will not ring even when given the cue from Android Device Manager to ring.  I have it set up on my phone, and am able to locate my phone just fine. However, when I click ring, my phone beeps once, and there is a notification that says "Android Device Manager" with the subheading "Ringing...", but my phone never actually rings.

Does anyone know why this happens, or better yet, how to fix this? Any help would be great.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6, and yes, Android Device Manager *is* set as an administrator on my phone.

edit: Upon looking into the Phone Administrator settings in Security, I found that the permissions do not mention anything about ringing the phone (https://goo.gl/photos/gt1iE6piQTVfYvnHA).  Is this because that permission isn't at the administrator level, or do you think it is unavailable for some odd reason?

Update: So I managed to figure out that the only way it will ring is if my notifications volume is on.  However, I don't usually have that on, and it will not turn that volume on full or even on at all by itself.

I also disabled battery optimization for Device Manager, but unfortunately it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: It may be that Samsung has an internal battery saving mechanism which prevents the device manager from receiving the notification. Idk if you can disable it for some apps...

Comment: @timoschwarzer What exactly do you mean by it preventing _device manager_  from receiving the notification?

Comment: I assume that you have access to a phone because you know it doesn't ring. Maybe, just maybe this will help: settings>apps>android device manager and under permisssions see if some isn't granited. You can try clearing app cache and rebooting. Also try setting notifications on priority for ADM maybe do a trick.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I already set notifications as priority and it doesn't work.  Also, I tried looking at the permissions before as well and all of the options are enabled. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, which unfortunately doesn't work either. Im honestly not sure if there is anything that I can do, but hopefully there is a fix

Comment: Well, maybe it's just temporarly. Try finding older version on google, and see what happens than

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Just tried it on a version from 2014, still have the same problem

Comment: Would you try with other apps rather than ADM?

Comment: @FiN I would, but I do prefer ADM, and I just want to know why this is happening more out of curiosity then anything.

Comment: @Mario I was looking about this problem on Google,it seems that you are not the only one... p.s. it seems that the Android OS is blocking the ringing

Comment: @FiN Unfortunately that knowledge doesn't bring me any comfort

Comment: what version of Android?

Comment: @MarkYisri 6.0.1

Comment: Try disabling battery optimization for Device Manager and other Google apps that may be involved in the ringing of that tone, make sure your device is not in DND/mute, and see if a competing service like Prey Anti-Lost works or not. Let me know how this goes.

Comment: @owlswipe Look at the update edit on my post please.I know I can use other services but I'd prefer using Device Manager and I'd like to know why also out of curiosity.

Comment: Mario, if you turn off your phone's ringer Device Manager just won't make noise (it's volume is determined by the ringer). It's supposed to turn your volume up all the way before ringing, but your phone might be preventing that. You can try making a recipe in MacroDroid/Tasker/Trigger to do the following: when I get the "ringing" notification, turn my ringer volume up, then wait a few minutes and lower it again. That should do the trick! Try this and let me know.

Comment: Posted a solution, tell me if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by Android Device Manager not being able to raise the ringer volume on your phone before ringing the alarm tone.

To solve this, you can create a [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) macro that will automatically raise your ringer whenever an Android Device Manager notification appears on your phone, so that the alarm tone will actually ring. MacroDroid defines a set of trigger(s), action(s) and constraint(s) as a macro.

1. Download the [MacroDroid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) for free on your phone.
2. You will need to create the following macro:

   - ***Trigger***:  Notification → Notification Received:
   - *From*: (hit `show non-launchable apps`) and select Google Play Services and Android Device Manager
   - *Text Content*: choose `contains` and type in "ringing" (or just some/all of the text from the notification that appears when you attempt to ring your phone; this might vary by phone).
   - ***Action***: Volume Change
   - Hit the checkbox next to "ringer" and slide the ringer slider up to something high, then press OK. Then hit the checkbox next to "Notification" and slide the notification slider up to something high as well.
   - ***Constraints***: none
3. Test out your Macro by attempting to ring your phone from [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) on your computer. If it works, you're done. If it doesn't, try the following:

   - Add an action to your macro to `Set Priority Mode`, set it to all.
   - Add an action to your macro to play a sound of your choice, that might work.
   - Ensure the Device Manager notification text matches that which you specified in your trigger.
   - Try changing the action to a ringer volume increase, a one-second `wait`, then a notification volume increase.

**Important Note:** If you want your ringer to quiet down again after Android Manager rings, you can add a `wait before next action` to your actions, then do a ringer volume change back down.

Hope this helps! Comment below if this doesn't work for you or if you have a question, I'll help you out if you need it.

Comment: When I try to install that macro it gives me an error... also I tried making my own and it works when I click test macro but nothing happens when I actually get the notification from Device Manager.

Comment: @Mario Have you enabled notification access for MacroDroid? Did you make any notification from Device Manager trigger the macro?

Comment: yes to both of those

Comment: @Mario Make your macro also send a notification as one of its actions, this will let you know when it runs. See if it runs at the right time.

Comment: It doesn't run at all, for some reason it's not realizing I'm getting a notification from Device Manager, because I don't get a notification at all from MacroDroid

Comment: @Mario Not sure what to say. Receiving any notification from Device Manager is the trigger, correct? And there are no constraints? If you made it right and it doesn't work, my only suggestion is to contact the developer.

Comment: @Mario Try disabling battery optimizations for MacroDroid.

Comment: I hate having to say this but I already did that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49399/discussion-between-mario-and-owlswipe).